# Extended WPF Toolkit - WatermarkPasswordBox prevent from typing in enter value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I have a small problem as title says with WatermarkPasswordBox. If I use normal WPF's PasswordBox I cant type there Enter key ( value is`\n`) which is fine. But when I use WatermarkPasswordBox from Extended WPF Toolkit its typing Enter value constantly.

I tried to do nothing on enter key in this way:

```
private void TextBox_Password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {

    }
}

private void TextBox_Password_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {

    }
}

private void TextBox_Password_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {

    }
}

private void TextBox_Password_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {

    }
}
```

but it not helps.. I really would like to use Extended WPF Toolkit's PasswordBox, but this is very annoying.

To be more precise: 
[image: How it looks]

Comment: "its typing Enter value constantly" - I'm afraid I don't understand that. Do you really mean you constantly get keypress events? And only for these controls?

Comment: I mean that when I click Enter on keyboard, then into Password box write `\n` value

Comment: It's not textboxes themselves that handle the enter key usually; instead, if the form contains a button marked as default, that button intercepts the enter key for the current dialog. This will also work with the extended WPF toolkit controls.

Comment: I just add a picture, so you can see how look password.. Its not `\n` char, its `\r`. Each character is an Enter key click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not textboxes themselves that handle the enter key usually; instead, if the form contains a button marked as default, that button intercepts the enter key for the current dialog. If you have such a button on the form, you won't need to handle the enter key explicitly.

But if you want to do it anyway, the way to do it is to handle the PreviewKeyDown event and set the Handled property of the EventArgs to true:

```
    private void WatermarkPasswordBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much.. So simple but the devil’s in the detail